# Android, image and text with button

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I'm try to have a button, but it doesn't really fit. Also the text "Family" still really quite work.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_settings"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/iconb"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/family_text" />
```

I tried this one, but no prevail:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/iconb"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />
```

Help?

Comment: What do you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a custom card view and then call it from your activity/fragment and then apply `setOnclickListener` or `onClick` .